# Schema-less AND relational database

Tags: self-join, document-database, nosql

I have thousands of documents of different types and therefore different fields. My task is to find pairs or a group of documents, with specific relations:

```
A.race='dwarf' and B.race='elfe' and C.profession='thief'
A.haircolor = C.haircolor and B.favorite_meal = C.favorite_meal
```

Is there a database which is schema-less and relational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a schema is part of the definition of a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), so a database can not be both schemaless and relational.

But when you are searching for a database which is good for modeling and analyzing relations between entities without enforcing a consistent schema, you could take a look at graph databases like [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/). These databases focus on defining entities mostly by their relation to other entities. They make it really easy to find entities which have common relations to other entities.